# How to add array in data table in asp?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I wrote this code.

```
 var array = JSON.parse(chartData);
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'ProductCategory1');
 data.addColumn('number', 'RevenuAmount1');
 for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++) {
     data.addRow(array[ProductCategory1], array[RevenuAmount1]);
```

Comment: You can get data with ajax call.. From C#, you need to get data in the same format or you can create your own format in javascript as well.. I am also doing it and it is working for me..

Comment: can plz tell me how do it